# Choose best output neuron function for 2 class classification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Which function is suitable for output neuron in 2 class classification problem with [0/1] output label ?

My answer was Hyperbolic Tangent Neuron - tanh(.)
But ans is not correct , it is logistics sigmoid neuron. 
So why we can't use Hyperbolic Tangent Neuron?

Comment: Tanh bounds the output from -1 to 1. I can see how it would be possible to use this as the output function, but I guess bounding from 0 to 1 would be more appropriate if the outputs you are looking to achieve are in fact 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly possible to use a Hyperbolic Tangent function for a binary classification if you train one class with positive targets and another with negative. Recall the range of the Hyperbolic Tangent is `(-1, 1)`.

However, it is far more common to use the Sigmoid activation function as it has a Probabilistic interpretation as it's range is `(0, 1)`.

If `P(class = 0)` is given by the activation of a Sigmoid, then `P(class = 1) = 1 - P(class = 0)`

For multiclass classification, the Softmax function is commonly used for it's similar Probabilistic properties.